# How to open .images file format

Tags: image, file, file-type

I'm currently attempting to open a .images file and I'm not sure how.

I've tried photoshop & some other adobe apps, I've also had a look at google and there's pretty much no info there, so i'm coming to stack overflow, seen as im assuming its a development format & im hoping someone will have experience with it

Comment: We don't know. You can open the file in a hex editor and look at the first couple of bytes ("magic number") to discover what kind of file format it's in. Or you can start by telling where you obtained it and go research in that direction.